# How to support mixed precision in custom Tensorflow layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras, tensorflow2.x

**When developing my own custom layers for `tf.keras`: how am I supposed to support mixed precision?**

The [documentation of mixed precision](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/mixed_precision) - a feature which is currently marked as experimental in Tensorflow 2.2 - only explains how to use it from a consumers perspective with predefined layers such as the `tf.keras.layers.Dense` one.

I already tried to guess it myself and found two - maybe relevant - details:

- The `dtype` property stays as `float32` by default when using 16-bit mixed precision.
- There is a `mixed_precision.get_layer_policy(layer)` method (see [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/mixed_precision/experimental/get_layer_policy)) and a `mixed_precision.global_policy()` method (see [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/mixed_precision/experimental/global_policy)) which could be used to retrieve the configured `compute_dtype` and `variable_dtype`.

Am I supposed to use the above `get_layer_policy`-method and just cast my variables into `compute_dtype` within the `call(...)` method of my layer? (And pass `variable_dtype` in my layers `build(...)` method to `add_weight(...)` when creating variables?)

For example, here is naive sample implementation of a standard dense neuron layer:

```py
  def call(self, input):
    policy = mixed_precision.get_layer_policy(self)
    bias = tf.cast(self._bias, policy.compute_dtype)
    weights = tf.cast(self._weights, policy.compute_dtype)
    y = tf.nn.bias_add(tf.matmul(input, weights), bias)
    outputs = self._activation(y)
    return outputs
```

Sure, nobody would implement such basic stuff themselves, that one is just for demonstration. But, would this be the way the Tensorflow team expects us to implement the `call(...)` methods of our custom layers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/video/gputechconf/gtc/2019/presentation/s91029-automated-mixed-precision-tools-for-tensorflow-training-v2.pdf) guide (slide 13-14) from nvidia mentions custom layers for mixed precision training.

You have to implement the method `cast_input()`. In this example the layer is casted to float16 when mixed precision is enabled:

```py
class CustomBiasLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

 def build(self, _):
   self.v = self.add_weight('v', ())
   self.built = True
  
 def call(self, inputs):
   return inputs + self.v

 def cast_inputs(self, inputs):
   # Casts to float16, the policy's lowest-precision dtype
   return self._mixed_precision_policy.cast_to_lowest(inputs)
```

I have not tried this myself, so please let me know if this works for you.